# Why does typedef not offer protection in function parameters?

Tags: c++, typedef

I was under the impression that a good use-case for typedef was to insure that the wrong type of argument was not passed to a function. But that doesn't seem to actually be enforced by the compiler.

Can someone tell me why the below compiles? And how I can achieve my goal of having a function take MyType and the compiler complaining if I try to pass YourType?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef std::string MyType;
typedef std::string YourType;

void PrintMyString(const MyType& my_type) {
  std::cout << my_type;
}

int main()
{
    MyType my_type = "Hello";
    YourType your_type = " World";
    PrintMyString(my_type);
    PrintMyString(your_type); // should fail?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`typedef`s are just an alias to a type, it does not make a new type.  If both `typedef`s alias the same type then you can interchange them.

It looks like you can use a strong typedef or you could wrap the type in a wrapper class and use the wrapper class as the function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Because `typedef` creates an alias, not a new type.  For that you need some sort of "strong typedef".  Boost has one.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of something outside of Boost I can use? Perhaps 'typedef' isn't what I want.

Comment: @cppuser1 Maybe a new class.

Answer (score 1):

This problem, of *phantom types*, comes up occaisonally:

- [boost strong typedef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp)
- [similar question on Programmer's stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/243154/c-strongly-typed-typedef).

I think the way to go is with something like this:

```
struct typedef_0 : public specific_type
{
// Add variadic perfect-forwarding ctor here.
};
```

This would create a type `typedef_0` that is "nearly interchangeable" with `specific_type`. If you wanted another one, you would call it some other thing, e.g., `typedef_1`.

You could use this to create a macro that achieves "strong" typedefness. Something like:

```
 #define MAKE_STRONG_TYPEDEF(ORIG_TYPE, NEW_TYPE) \
 struct NEW_TYPE : public ORIG_TYPE \
 { \
 template<typename ...T>NEW_TYPE(T &&..t) : \
     ORIG_TYPE(std::forward(T...)(t)){}
 };
```

(Didn't try to compile it, but that's the general idea.)